# About JUnit XML Output

Tags: java, xml, junit

Say I have a class "P" which extends TestCase in Junit. Now for xml format this looks like below

```
<testsuit tests="1">
   <testcase classname="P"  name="PTest"/>
</testsuit>
```

This works for me. But for the following situation I have not found any solution.

I have written a class say "X" which extents TestCase. I have another class say "Y" which extends "X".

Now how can I write it in xml format for junit.

Answer (score 0):

That looks to be very old junit style. Check out [Junit 4](https://github.com/junit-team/junit). You can just annotate test methods with `@Test` in a plain old class (no need to inherit from TestCase or use any XML).